# Pros and cons of separating olfactory and respiratory systems?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, fauna

So, I watched [James Cameron's "Avatar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film)) a few days ago and something on the wildlife of Pandora caught my attention:

Most* of the creatures seem to have distinct organs for breathing and for smelling things.

Here's some pictures of the "Direhorse". They have large orifices on the side of their necks that are often shown to move in sync with their breathing. Let's call those the "breathing nostrils". But they *also* have tiny orifices on the tip of their snouts that are in prime smelling position, so I'm assuming they are "smelling nostrils".

[image: yummy]

I admit the "smelling nostrils" are a bit fuzzy, so here's a second picture where they should be more visible, right above the mouth.

[image]

This pattern is present in many other creatures in the film, such as the "Thanator"...

[image: kitty]

...and the "Viperwolf".

[image]

So, my question is **what is the benefit of having your olfactory organs away from your breathing organs?**

---

Now that I think about it, real life frogs also have "smelling nostrils" as well as "breathing 'nostrils'" in their skin, but I guess they're slightly distinct because both pairs are respiratory.

[image]

---

**The Na'Vi, notably, seem to both breathe and smell through the same orifices, but that can be easily explained by the film crew wanting them to look much more human-like.*

Comment: The vast majority of vertebrates have no linkage between their olfactory and respiratory systems. We call them fish; fish do not breathe through their nostrils. (And frogs most definitely have one single pair of nostrils, just like us.)

Comment: Please avoid asking subjective questions ("what is the benefit of X?" is always subjective). Here's my point: I could answer by saying, "your environment could have a toxin that, if absorbed into the bloodstream, would kill the creature, but the concentration of that toxin results in an odor that represents a nearby food source that's required for life, therefore the redundant air sacks needed for disconnected smelling and breathing could evolve." But look at how much supposition I had to invent to propose a dubious (and arguably unbelievable) answer? (\*continued\*)

Comment: Consequently, the question seems more of an invitation to a discussion (off-topic) than it does a search for an objective answer to develop a world (on-topic). Therefore, VTC Opinion-based (too subjective).

Comment: @JBH u just not familiar with the topic, that' why it looks like that for you - snakes, rats, and I suspect butterflies as well - do have separate or semi-separate systems. Advantages are objective in therms - they all are hell sensitive. I also not that much knowledgeable on the topic, but I was impressed by rat's system once I discovered it. Maybe sensitivity is because they can regulate time spend on detection of smells, clean it better - like we may do some times slowly and steady inhaling to feel smell better.

Comment: @MolbOrg -- Rats are mammals and thus sniff through their noses. Some mammals do indeed have an accessory odor collection system in the roof of their mouths (cats, e.g.). Some animals have more powerful sniffers than others. Snakes sniff through their noses too, as well as through their mouths. Snakes also "sniff" heat. JBH's point isn't one of anatomy, but rather one of open-ended discussion (off-topic) vs focussed (on topic).

Comment: OP: you might want to clarify what your question actually is. You gave us half a dozen examples of animals from a third party intellectual property --- i.e., something that isn't yours. We're not here to satisfy idles curiosity about about what happens in the Avatar World. If you are working on your own fictional world and would like to address this topic, then please edit your question accordingly! Until then, VTC until you can sort it out.

Comment: @elemtilas "thus sniff through their noses" - they do, kinda, the reason why I used word semi as well, they have special sensing organ in which odors are dissolved in mucus or something like that, and they somewhat squeeze all that through it to sense smells. if u remove it they stop distinguish males and females etc. I'm not sure how common or unusual that is for mammals, but I find it smart and useful. But I guess we can agree that separation, in general, isn't unusual in nature - insects maybe most or all, etc

Comment: @elemtilas as JBH's point - he says "avoid asking subjective questions" - so he talks about some subjectivism here, while it is a real evolutionary situation with its pros and cons

Comment: @MolbOrg --- The issue is that "pros and cons" are fundamentally human constructs. We might anthropomorphise an animal, and say they "weigh the pros and cons", but's that's beside the point here! Pros and cons are by nature "of the structure of an  internal debate or discussion" --- shall I do this, or shan't I? Mought this be better or that? Clearly off topic here! You bring up evolution. Evolution NEVER debates, never discusses.

Comment: @elemtilas "The issue is that "pros and cons" are fundamentally human constructs." - say it to extinct species, which did that long before humankind project. do not push your anthropomorphism on me.

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion-based: if it's evolved here on Earth as stated there must be an evolutionary advantage to splitting or not merging the two functions. And please note the question in the body is "what is the benefit...?" and not "list the pros and cons" as found in the title.

Comment: @MolbOrg -- Exactly. Evolution didn't -- and doesn't -- care whether species live or die. It has no pros and it has no cons. It simply presents its random changes in the genetic environment of a species and that's that. It is the ultimate in unanthropomorphologising of life forces.

Comment: @elemtilas yes, almost, but "random changes ... that's that." - no, u even correctly said it yourself - it has a result or even results. change is incorporated in that kind or not, and a set of treats allow them to survive or they go extinct. idk maybe that pros and cons has some strange connotations in engish, I'm not capable to play the game too long as I'm not so vocabulary rich - advantages disadvantage, positive negative influence, pluses minuses - all I know. pros cons are shorter, and sure it all just from The evolutionary perspective, from the perspective of a result - life or death.

Answer (score 0):

If the environment has vents that can make the air highly toxic, or there are predators or plants that can expel a highly toxic gas, then it would be reasonable for the creature to have a respiratory system that can be completely closed off for brief intervals, while the olfactory sense continues to monitor the air quality. The creature would want to sense the air without actually breathing it.

Comment: there's also that if you have them separated, then any damage to one wont hinder the function of the other, as well as the advantage that when separate the respiratory vents can have more filtration as it wont ruin their ability to smell, meaning better resistances to airborne hazards, and at the same time gives them the option of having more sensitive olfactory vents as they dont need to be filtered as much